# Helltooth 6-piece set bonus, does it apply to existing pets or only on recast?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got the 6th Helltooth item and the 6-piece set item bonus reads as follows:

> After casting Wall of Death, gain 1400% increased damage for 15 seconds to your primary skills, Acid Cloud, Firebats, Zombie Charger, **Zombie Dogs, Gargantuan**, Grasp of the Dead, Piranhas, and Wall of Death.

Since I rarely re-cast the Zombie Dogs or Gargantuan spells, these tend to stay with me for a long time.

So the question is this. After I cast Wall of Death, and thus gain the above bonus, will my existing Zombie Dogs and Gargantuan gain the bonus, or do I have to recast them?

Answer (score 4):

The effect applies to your existing zombie dogs and Gargantuan for 15 seconds. You don't need to recast them.